# How to delete a user's info(even if he/she is not currently logged in) from firebase database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a piece of code to delete a user's information from firebase database using angular. I have the required user's email id with me. The structure of the database is as follows.

```js
users
  |_unique key
  |      |_email:value
  |      |_tag:value
  |_unique key
         |_...
```

Okay, so I have the email id and using it's value in equalTo() of orderByChild() I get the user using 'value' method. Now, I want to access this user's unique key in order to delete his\her data. This is how I go about it .

```js
deleteUser(email)
  {  console.log(email);
     var userid;
     firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("value",(snapshot)=>{
     userid=snapshot.key;
     console.log(snapshot);
     console.log(userid)  
     firebase.database().ref('users/userid').remove();
     }) ;
     
     
  }
```

But for some reason, instead of the unique key getting stored in the 'userid' variable,'users' is getting stored and I am not able to delete the required information. Please Help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this first you have to index your child "email" in rules then

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      ".indexOn": "email",
      ".read" : "auth.uid !== null",
      ".write" : "auth.uid !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

After writing this rules, now use this function

```
deleteUser(email)
  {  
console.log(email);
var userid;
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value', function(data) { data.forEach(function(child) { 
userid = child.key
console.log(userid);
firebase.database().ref('users/'+userid).remove(); })});
}
```

Comment: write the rules fro read and write according to your scheme, for try, now keep both values true @Schimay

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! Could you explain what exactly the forEach is doing in this case ?

Comment: Yeah, since you used "value", it will call parent node, insted of child, so to access the child elements of the parentNode, you must use forEach, if you know the parent key, then there is no use of foreach. If you use child_added or changed or removed instaed of value, then there is no use of for each in that case.

Comment: since you use email to orderby, which is under a unique key, so you have to index it on rules.